# Cannot add Enumeration field in Jhipster entity-generator

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to create an entity using Jhipster with the following command.

```
(My-base-project-directory)$jhipster entity Author
```

This entity has a Nationality Enum inside it. When i want to add the field, Jhipster asks the following questions:

```
Do you want to add a field to your entity? Y
What is the name of your field? nationality
What is the type of your field? Enumeration (Java enum type)
What is the class name of your enumeration?
```

when i want to input "nationality" or "nationalityEnum" as class name, i get the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

I'm using Jhipster auto-generated monolithic project with java and react and I run the commands in my project's root directory. my Jhipster version is 7.0.1.
I would appreciate if any one could help.

Comment: This is a known issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/14906

Comment: I wonder why I never encountered this link in my google searches. Well, at least now I understand why the same question was deleted by it's author in Stackoverflow. :-\